# Disabling navigation drawer from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-toolbar

I have an app with a navigation drawer and 4 navigation items (Fragments). In one of the Fragments, I have a tab layout set up with a view pager (3 more Fragments).

From one of these inner fragments, I want to disable/enable the navigation drawer dynamically. Basically, on a button press, I want to restrict access to the navigation drawer (and the re-enable on pressing it again).

How would I do it?

I tried accessing the `DrawerLayout` of the parent activity from this inner fragment. But I see no methods to enable/disable the navigation drawer.

The way I've added the drawer to my main Activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

(and of course I've added `toggle.syncState()` from within the `onPostCreate` method.

Comment: Use `setDrawerLockMode()` for the `DrawerLayout`, and `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Comment: @MikeM. Setting `setDrawerLockMode()` stopped the swiping-gesture. But to set `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()`, how do I access `ActionBarDrawerToggle` from within my Fragment?

Comment: Ideally, you should be doing this through an `interface` that the Activity implements, where the `interface`'s method in the Activity calls those above-mentioned methods.

Comment: @MikeM. Yep, I tried to do it. But things got very complicated because I'm trying to do this within one of the Fragments in the ViewPager of a Tab layout, which in turn is contained in a Fragment owned by the main activity :-/ If you could provide any hints on doing this (like pseudo-code? or a basic code-structure?), it would be really great

Comment: "But things got very complicated because I'm trying to do this within one of the Fragments in the ViewPager of a Tab layout, which in turn is contained in a Fragment owned by the main activity" - That's not really relevant, as the Fragment is still attached directly to the Activity. Cast `getActivity()` to your `interface`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A clean way to do this is to create an `interface` that the `Activity` implements, through which the `Fragment` can call a method local to the `Activity` that handles the drawer lock and toggle button states. For example:

```
public interface DrawerLocker {
    public void setDrawerEnabled(boolean enabled);
}
```

In the `Activity`'s `interface` method, we simply figure the lock mode constant for the `DrawerLayout#setDrawerLockMode()` call, and call `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DrawerLocker {

    public void setDrawerEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        int lockMode = enabled ? DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED :
                                 DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED;
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(lockMode);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(enabled);
    }

    ...
}
```

In the `Fragment`, we merely need to cast the hosting `Activity` to the `interface`, and call the `setDrawerEnabled()` method accordingly. For example, to lock the drawer shut:

```
((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(false);
```

---

NB: Since version 23.2.0 of the v7 appcompat support library, `ActionBarDrawerToggle` respects the `DrawerLayout`'s lock mode, and will not toggle the drawer state if it is locked. This means that it is not strictly necessary to use `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()`, though it might be desirable to still do so in order to provide the user a visual indication that the toggle is disabled.

Comment: This solution worked, thank you. How do I change the icon so it is not seen.  I am having trouble managing the icon in general.

Comment: Are you looking for `ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` maybe?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); worked for me. Thanks @MikeM.

Answer (score 1):

for Kotlin language, these two lines:
[first line is for closing the drawer,
second line is for setting its mode to "LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED" (to make it disabled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYwHF.png)

```
drawerLayout.close()
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
```

"drawerLayout" is defined like this:
[first line: declaring an instance of a DrawerLayout object
second line: assigning a value to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV6C2.png)

```
private lateinit var drawerLayout:DrawerLayout
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_container)
```