# How to disable manual sliding-out of navigation view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have two navigation views in my Activity. One enters from the right and the other enters from the left.

In the navigtionview that enters from from the left, different fragments are started when when the items are clicked. And also, this same navigationview has menu items which is common to all the launched fragments. I don't have any problem with this one.

Now, the navigationview that enters from the right has menu items which are only peculiar to the particular fragment started when the first item in the left entering navigationview is clicked. What this means is that, when you clicked the first item in the left entering navigation drawer, a fragament is started,  and items in the right entering navigationview has items related to this fragment.

So,  this right navigationview is stared when a menuitem in the toolbar is clicked. And this menu item is not visible when other fragments (apart from the aforementioned) is in view.

The problem I have is that, even when the right entering navigationview cannot be launched through the menuitem in other fragments, it can still be started by sliding the right edge of the screen. So I want to totally disable the sliding feature of this right entering navigationview,  so it can only be launched when the menu item is clicked.

### Codes

**activity_main**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:openDrawer="start">

     <include
         layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
         app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/cat_nav_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="end"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

         /** This navigationview enters from the right, I start a fragment with framelayout below.
         The fragment contains a recyclerview **/

         <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/transport_cat_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Snippets of MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            }
        };


        drawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }

        }


 ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            }
        };


        drawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        Fragment fragment;


        if (id == R.id.menu_cars) {
            fragment = new CarsFragment();
            startCarsFrag() //Method to start CarsFragment()
            //The right entering drawer should only be enabled for this fragment
        }


        if (id == R.id.menu_trains) {
            fragment = new TrainsFragment();
            startTrainFrag() //Method to start TrainsFragment
        }

        if (id == R.id.menu_lorries) {
            fragment = new LorriesFragment();
             startLorriesFrag() //Method to start LorriesFragment

        }
        if (drawer != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean to do this from the `Fragment`s themselves, but in any case, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249563/disabling-navigation-drawer-from-fragment) should help. The `DrawerLayout#setDrawerLockMode()` method is what you're looking for. In your case, you'd call it with a second argument to specify which drawer to lock/unlock; e.g., `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(lockMode, GravityCompat.END)`. Disregard the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` stuff, since it's not applicable to that second drawer.

Comment: @MikeM. Please can you enter your comment as an answer? I used it with the second parameter and it fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DrawerLayout#setDrawerLockMode()` method is what you're looking for. When locked, a drawer `View` cannot be dragged open/closed, though it will still respond to the `openDrawer()` and `closeDrawer*()` methods.

Since you're using two drawers, and want to lock only the one, you'll need to call the method with a second argument to indicate which drawer to lock/unlock. For example, to lock your secondary drawer closed:

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);
```