# How to disable drawer option in specific fragments of an activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have an activity with 5 fragments, I used drawer layout in my activity for a drawer, but I want to use(enable) the drawer in only fragment 2 and I want to disable the drawer option in remaining fragments.

Can any one help me how to do this?

Comment: Show this answer it may be helpfull to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/36250280/5773037

Comment: Do you mean to disable the whole drawer, or just certain items in it?

Comment: @MikeM. yes! i hide the button in toolbar but if you slide from the left side of the screen drawer is still coming.

Comment: Yeah, then you wanna lock the drawer, as demonstrated in my answer that Nikunj linked. You can omit the toggle stuff there, if you're already handling that yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling navigation drawer from fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249563/disabling-navigation-drawer-from-fragment)

Comment: `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, drawerView);` use this code to lock drawer layout.

Comment: @praneethkumar are u satisfied?

Comment: I was trying all the options! will get back to you if It fix my prob!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put two methods in the your `activity`, one to disable the `drawer` and one to enable it again, like so:

```
public void lockDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}


public void unlockDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
}
```

Then in your `fragments` `onCreateView(...)` method put:

```
fragmentInteractionListener.lockDrawer();
```

for the `fragments` where the `drawer` should stay shut and for the `fragments` where the `drawer` should stay open put:

```
fragmentInteractionListener.unlockDrawer();
```

**P.S:** for tutorials in how to correctly implement a `fragment` interaction listener see:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: this isn't the way to communicate between fragments & activities. 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: if you read my P.S i acknowledge that, but for ease of demonstrating the concept i use the getActivity instead @k0sh

Comment: o0ops, i didn't see that, but you should've provided a proper example as this might just cause the OP other issues. anyway, i got back my -1, +1

Comment: No problem and thanks for the +1, i changed my answer and added a link to the tutorial you suggested instead @k0sh

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this is supposed to work. What is `fragmentInteractionListener`?

Comment: Hi @Houman, fragmentInteractionListener is an interface class that is implemented by the activity, you can use fragmentInteractionListener to "talk" to the activity from the fragment. The documentation in the link has been updated but the naming convention it used to use was fragmentInteractionListener making this answer easier to follow