# Communication from Activity to multiple Fragment

Tags: android, interface, callback

I have four fragments in a single activity, Now i want to send data from activity to all fragments. Through Interface i can communicate only one fragment, Please advice how can i achieve this.

Comment: Do you want all fragments to have access to a variable in the activity?

Comment: Shared Preferences can help.

Comment: @MichaelStoddart YES

Comment: You can make a common public method in activity and as all fragments are in that activity you can access that method like this ((MainActivity)getActivity).getCommonFunction();

Comment: @NewbieAndroid Means create a four public methods in activity.

Comment: No if you want same data in all four fragments just create one public method with the parameters you want and use that method in all four fragments.

Comment: @deep , NewbieAndroid is right, if you create a method in your activity and get it to return the variable you want then you can access this in your fragment, however the correct way to call back to an activity from a fragment can be found in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953366/how-to-disable-drawer-option-in-specific-fragments-of-an-activity/39954936#39954936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data from Activity to Fragment using `interface` as follows.

**1. Create interface** which is used to pass data from Activity to Fragment `FragmentCommunicator.java`.

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator{
   public void passDataToFragment(Object data);
}
```

**2.  Define fragment** named `ExampleFragment.java`.

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragments implements FragmentCommunicator{

    //as per Android Fragment documentation an empty constructor
    public ExampleFragment(){    
    }

    public static ExampleFragment newInstance(){
      return new ExampleFragment();
    }

    ...

    //FragmentCommunicator interface implementation
    @Override
    public void passDataToFragment(Object data) {
       //you will get data here from activity, here we used data to set textview.
       textView.setText((String)data);
    }

}
```

**3.  Send data** from Activity `ExampleActivity.java`

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
    ...

    public void sendDataToFragment(Fragment fragment, Object data){
       if (fragment instanceof FragmentCommunicator) {
           fragmentCommunicator = (FragmentCommunicator) fragment;
           fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(data)
       }
    }
 }
```

Hope that helps!